# Cannot dismiss a VIewController after dismissing a MediaplayerViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller presenting a MediaViewController and after that I cannot get the first view to dismiss.

Apparently it might not work if both views are dismissed animated:YES, but I have tried all variants and still no luck.

I create and present the MediaPlayerViewController like so

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [mp moviePlayer].controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [[mp moviePlayer] prepareToPlay];
    [[mp moviePlayer] setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [mp moviePlayer].fullscreen = YES;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

The following code should dismiss the views

```
-(void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{       
    AppstersAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppstersAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

   // [appDelegate continueSetup];

    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];

    [appDelegate.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

The viewController on the appDelegate is the rootViewController

I have also tried calling dismissModalViewControllerAnimated on self, but it didnt solve the issue.

The weird thing is that this is happening with each view that is presenting a movieViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Try `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated];`